# How many concurrent requests can a webhook in GCP handle?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, webhooks, google-cloud-run

I'm working on creating a webhook in GCP (using either Cloud Functions or Cloud Run) which would receive around 1200 requests on a particular day once in a month. And it is possible that most of these requests happen around the same time.

Would either of these services be able to handle 1200 requests around the same time?

1. Cloud Functions
2. Cloud Run

If not, what are the other alternatives? Please advise.

Comment: It's all about server resources. Giving example on PHP. Every request summons a new php worker which uses like 40 MB RAM alone. Script may use more RAM in time. So, to handle such request server requires 5 GB RAM for PHP alone. IOPS limit and CPU limit is a thing too.

Comment: @norahCii - where did you get those numbers?

Comment: Both Cloud Run and Cloud Functions auto-scale. Depending on the configuration, thousands of requests can be handled at the same time. The default setting for Cloud Run is 80 requests per instance. That can be adjusted based upon the resources requires to handle a single request. Then you can configure a minimum number of instances. Assuming 50 requests per instance, you only need 20 instances to handle 1,000 requests per second. Those numbers are approximations, but scaling to 10s of thousands is easily achieved.

Comment: Adding to @JohnHanley's comment, in addition to autoscaling 2nd generation cloud functions (which leverage Cloud Run under the hood) allow you to configure the minimum number of instances and concurrent invocations (that helps you to minimize errors that stem from cold starts - but you will incur higher costs to maintain live instances and concurrency).

Comment: Couldn't find info on net. Something that special with my server setup i suppose @john hanley

Comment: Here is a link on configuration minimum instances. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances

Comment: Here is a link on auto scaling: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling

Comment: Hopefully, those links plus my answer will help you maximize the feature sets of those services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am combining the comments from myself and @TheAddonDepot.

Both Cloud Run and Cloud Functions auto-scale. Depending on the configuration, thousands of requests can be handled at the same time.

The default setting for Cloud Run is 80 requests per instance. That can be adjusted based upon the resources requires to handle a single request. Then you can configure a minimum number of instances. Assuming 50 requests per instance, you only need 20 instances to handle 1,000 requests per second. Those numbers are approximations, but scaling to 10s of thousands is easily achieved.

Autoscaling 2nd generation cloud functions (which leverage Cloud Run under the hood) allow you to configure the minimum number of instances and concurrent invocations (that helps you to minimize errors that stem from cold starts - but you will incur higher costs to maintain live instances and concurrency).

Comment: Thanks. I'm expecting high traffic (~1500 requests) only on a particular day (fixed) of a month. On all other days, the traffic would be mush lesser (~60 to 100 requests). With this requirement, would Cloud Functions also be a good cost effective option? Because AFAIK, Cloud Functions is serverless and cost is incurred only when the function runs.

Comment: @abitgcp01 - yes, Cloud Functions will support your requirements. Functions auto-scales as required by traffic. One request per year, or 10,000 per minute, you only pay for what is used (invocations).